# Please help me find out if the colums of $A$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}3&1&4&1&5&9\\2&6&5&3&5&8\\9&7&9&3&2&3\\8&4&6&2&6&4\\3&3&8&3&2&7\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Do the columns of $A$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$?

I'm really lost in class. Please show steps and answers that I can learn. Please help...
Thank you

This is the rref.

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&-23/11\\0&1&0&0&0&4/3\\0&0&1&0&0&106/33\\0&0&0&1&0&-214/33\\0&0&0&0&1&50/33\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Uhh, digits of $\pi$.

Comment: Have you tried row reducing this matrix?  What do you get?

Comment: Yes, I did rref and got

Comment: So the RREF has five linearly independent rows, and in turn the row rank of $A$ is $5$. Yet the row rank is always equal to the column rank. Hence $A$ has five linearly independent columns.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ has **six** columns, but $\dim\mathbb{R}^5=5$. So the columns of $A$ certainly do not form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$. So I assume you meant to ask whether the columns of $A$ *span* $\mathbb{R}^5$. This is equivalent to showing that the rank of $A$ is $5$. So, you can use elementary row/column operations to transform $A$ to a row/column reduced echelon form, and check how many nonzero rows/columns are there.

Answer (score 1):

It has $6$ columns, each of dimension $5$. A space has dimension $5$ (by definition) if and only if it has a basis with $5$ basis vectors. A basis just corresponds to a *coordinate system* (which is probably oblique and the lengths are not necessarily equally measured on the axes).

There's a basic theorem of vector spaces, that if any basis has $n$ elements, then *all* bases have $n$ elements.
In consequence, no $6$ vectors can form a basis for the $5$ dimensional space.

Comment: So since it has 5 rows and that matches the exponent of R, the columns of A form a basis of R^5?

Comment: I thought the exponent of R represented how many components each vector has...

Comment: There are six columns, so, no, they don't form a basis. However, any $5$ of them *do form* a basis. The culomns form a basis iff the elimination can give you the identity matrix.